# Can I inherit from data odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have this from the OCA:

```
<odoo noupdate="1">
    <record id="medical_specialty_adult_mental" model="medical.specialty">
        <field name="code">408467006</field>
        <field name="name">Adult mental illness</field>
    </record>

    <record id="medical_specialty_anesthetics" model="medical.specialty">
        <field name="code">394577000</field>
        <field name="name">Anesthetics</field>
    </record>

    others speciality .....
</odoo>
```

My question is: how can I inherit one of the speciality?

Comment: What do you mean by inherting? What is your goal? And do you have this module by OCA installed?

Comment: @CZoellner yes, i've this module by OCA installed, there is some speciality in the module (in english), i searched for their traduction in french but no result, so now, i want to inherit the speciality and modify the name (write it in french)

Answer (score 0):

To inherit it you must write it in the same way that it was defiined in the original module with the difference that in the id put first the name of the original module and followed by a dot and the id.

You only need to put the fields that you are going to modify.

```
<odoo noupdate="1">
    <record id="original_module_name.medical_specialty_adult_mental" model="medical.specialty">
        <field name="name">new_name</field>
    </record>

    <record id="original_module_name.medical_specialty_anesthetics" model="medical.specialty">
        <field name="code">new_code</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Remember to add the file to the **manifest**

Comment: That won't work because both records are marked as "no update". First you have to unmark them, then write on their name fields (like in your answer right now) and then you should mark them back again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to inherit these records, first of all, you need to make `noupdate` value `False`. To do this, use this function below:

```
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('name', '=', 'medical_specialty_adult_mental'), ('module', '=', 'MODULE_NAME_HERE')]" />
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
</function>
```

Then, you can make the modifications you wish:

```
<record id="MODULE_NAME_HERE.medical_specialty_adult_mental" model="medical.specialty">
    <field name="code">408467006</field>
    <field name="name">Adult mental illness</field>
    <field name="NEW_FIELD">NEW_FIELD_VALUE</field>
</record>
```

And, right after that, you can make this record's noupdate value `True` again.

```
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('name', '=', 'medical_specialty_adult_mental'), ('module', '=', 'MODULE_NAME_HERE')]" />
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
</function>
```

Do not forget to replace `MODULE_NAME_HERE` with the right module name.